# Plotly flips ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

I want to plot `boxplot` using only summary statistics (`INPUT` is summary statistics for each `ID`).
`plot1` is what I want, but when I convert it to a [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) object something goes wrong (ie., `plotly` flips `boxplot`).
However, if I plot `boxplot` the usual way (not using `stat = "identity"`) everything works fine.

**Question:** Why `plotly` "flips" summarised `ggplot2` boxplot and how to avoid this?

```
library(broom)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# Generate random data
# Calculate statistics
INPUT <- rnorm(100) %>%
    matrix(10) %>%
    apply(2, function(x) tidy(summary(x))) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    mutate(ID = letters[1:10])

# Plot boxplot using statistics
plot1 <- ggplot(INPUT, aes(ID)) +
    geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", aes(
        lower = q1,
        upper = q3,
        middle = median,
        ymin = minimum,
        ymax = maximum))

# Only ggplot2 produces right result
plot1; ggplotly(plot1)
```

[image]
[image]

```
# Plot boxplot usual way
plot2 <- INPUT %>%
    gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
    ggplot(aes(ID, value)) +
        geom_boxplot()

# ggplot2 and plotly produces right result
plot2; ggplotly(plot2)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my opinion, `plot2` and  `ggplotly(plot2)` are rather different, too.

Comment: @MarcoSandri yes, they aren't identical, but general pattern is kinda the same.

Comment: [Same issue?](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/565)