# How do I draw a plotly boxplot with calculated values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have the following code for creating a boxplot in ggplot2:

```
throughput <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
response_time_min <- c(9, 19, 29, 39, 49)
response_time_10  <- c(50, 55, 60, 60, 61)
response_time_med <- c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
response_time_90  <- c(201, 201, 250, 200, 230)
response_time_max <- c(401, 414, 309, 402, 311)
df <- data.frame(throughput, response_time_min, response_time_10, response_time_med,response_time_90, response_time_max)
df

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(throughput),ymax = response_time_max,upper = response_time_90,
                   y = response_time_med,
                   middle = response_time_med, 
                   lower = response_time_10, 
                   ymin = response_time_min), stat = "identity")
g
```

But now when I want to apply `ggplotly(g)` the graph does not render correctly. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Right now it's not possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004079/plotly-flips-ggplot2-boxplot

Comment: The `y` aesthetic is not needed.

Comment: Without the `y` aesthetic, the graph will not render

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 90th percentile and 10th percentile can be done.  Assuming they are q3 and q1, respectively, the code below

```
bp <- plot_ly(color=c("orange")) %>% 
    add_trace(lowerfence = response_time_min, q1 = response_time_10, 
              median = response_time_med, q3 = response_time_90, 
              upperfence = response_time_max, type = "box") %>% 
    layout(xaxis=list(title="throughput"),
           yaxis=list(title="response_time"))
  bp
```

gives the following output:

[image: output]